# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Prove that the set $E=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|\lim_{y\rightarrow x}f(y)=+\infty\} $ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

This is a problem from a real analysis book. The book gives a hint: Consider $g(x)=\arctan f(x)$. However, I don't think it makes any difference. I try to find an injection form $E$ into a countable set. But I've got completely no idea, and wondered if the statement was wrong.

Comment: I don't think the statement is wrong. Heuristically, a function needs some interval along which to approach infinity, and if you break up the real line into intervals in any way you can count them.

Comment: There is the possibility that some points in E are not isolated. The interval method doesn't work here.

Comment: Good point. I really can't think of a counterexample but obviously that's not an argument. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Assume that $E = \{x : \lim_{y\to x} f(y) = \infty\}$ is uncountable. For $n\in \mathbb N,$ let $E_n = \{x\in E: f(x) < n\}.$ Show that some $E_{n}$ is uncountable, hence some point of this $E_{n}$ is a limit point of $E_n.$

Comment: Can someone explain where the contradiction is?

Comment: Let $x\in E_n$ be a limit point of $E_n.$ Then there is a sequence $x_k$ in $E_n\setminus \{x\}$ converging to $x.$ We have $f(x_k) < n$ for every $k,$ hence $f(x_k) \not \to \infty.$ This is a contradiction because $x\in E_n \subset E,$ i.e. $\lim_{y\to x} f(y)=\infty.$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some further commentary:

1. **Does the hint help at all**? (After all, the elegant  and brief answer by  @zhw did not need it.) Sometimes hints can seem rather oblique.  In this case
   the hint evidently intends the student to reduce the problem to one that is already solved.  The composition $ g(x)=\arctan  f(x)$ converts the unbounded situation to a bounded one so that the limit is finite at each point of the set $E$.

So in fact all one needs to realize is that for every $x\in E$ the limit $\lim_{y\to x} g(x)$
exists and is different from $g(x)$.  That means that the set $E$ contains only removable discontinuities  of the function 
$g$ and consequently, by a theorem (evidently already proved in the source textbook), is countable.

2. **Is this problem interesting**?  By  that I mean does it really reveal anything about the structure of real functions in general, or is it just some textbook problem that pushes the student to apply some theorem or technique.

If we view it from a more general point of view we can learn quite a bit more about real functions and limits.

If 
$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is an
 arbitrary function one defines a number $$r\in \overline{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}  \cup \{-\infty\}$$
to be a *right cluster value* of $f$ at $x$ if there is at least
one sequence $x_n\searrow x$ for which $f(x_n)\to r$.  The set of all right cluster values at $x$ is denoted $\Lambda_f^+(x)$.  It is a nonempty closed set (i.e., closed in $\overline{\mathbb R}$.)
The left cluster set at $x$ is similarly defined and notated as
 $\Lambda_f{}^-(x)$.

> **Theorem** (W. H. Young 1908)   If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is an arbitrary function then the sets  $$E^+= \left\{x\in \mathbb R:
>   f(x)\not\in \Lambda_f^+(x)\right\} \ \ and \ \ E^-= \left\{x\in
>   \mathbb R: f(x)\not\in \Lambda_f{}^{-}(x)\right\} $$ are countable.

The problem posed here is a very special case of this in which
$\Lambda_f^+(x)=\Lambda_f{}^-(x)=\{\infty\}$ at each point of the given set $E$.

The proof is not hard, using ordinary and familiar techniques at this level.  For each point $x\in E^+$ there are integers $m$ and $n$ so that whenever $x<z<x+\frac1n$ one has $$|f(z)-f(x)|>\frac1m.$$ Let $E_{mn}$ be the set of all points $x\in E^+$ that have this property for $m$ and $n$.  Evidently
the union of the family of sets $\{E_{mn}\}$ is all of $E^+$.

Now just observe that if $u$, $v\in E_{mn}$ with $0<v-u<\frac1n$ then $|f(v)-f(u)|>\frac1m$.  Conclude that $E_{mn}$ must be countable and so also must be $E^+$.

This analysis using cluster values shows that questions of this type are not really about limits themselves.  Young didn't use this language and, in fact, his theorem was overlooked for some time and rediscovered later when cluster sets were introduced in this and other settings.

Comment: Thanks for that informative post.

Comment: Personal anecdote: As a first-year graduate student I audited, for a brief time, a course taught by L.C. Young, the son of W.H. Young and Grace Chisolm Young, at UW-Madison. I had heard by word of mouth from students and faculty that here was a an "old school" mathematician of great merit, certainly worth seeing. So I decided to attend a few classes. Continued in next post …

Comment: It was difficult for me. I would not say Professor Young was gifted in the areas of lecturing/teaching/elocution, but I was 22 and fresh out of college so what did I know? I lasted only a week or two. I remember the last lecture I attended, wherein Prof. Young announced that he had been working ten years on the problem he had just described with various gesticulations and chalk markings. Then he said "ten years is really not that long to work on an important problem." I'm afraid that was it for this graduate student in Prof. Young's class.

Comment: @zhw.  Thanks for the story.  I never met L.C.Young but I did meet his sister Rosalind at a meeting in Aberystwyth in 1976 where the family had lived long ago.  She wasn't at the same level as her brother, but she was charming and I had what felt like a connection to the family since I had much studied the papers of the parents.  In the end I even got to co-author a paper on the real  analysis contributions of the Youngs.   I envy your chance to see L.C. Young.  A friend of mine says that he invariably fell asleep in talks but always woke at the end to ask the most insightful questions.